# What is the result of a dereferenced post incremented pointer being assigned to another dereferenced post incremented pointer in c++?

Tags: c++

I encountered code similiar to the following in a c++, and I am unsure exactly what it does.

```
*x++ = *y++;
```

`x` and `y` are references to `uint32`s.

I understand that `++` is the post-increment operator, and `*` dereferences, but am still unsure of exactly what this does.

Comment: Akin to `*x = *y; x++; y++`

Comment: Make the value pointed to by x equal to the value pointed to by y and then increment both of the values pointed to by x and y?

Comment: I think I am wrong, and it is actually incrementing the pointers instead of values pointed to.

Comment: Right. The dereferenced values are used as they exist `*x = *y;`, then the pointer increment is applied as a side effect.

Comment: Somebody please create an answer, in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions. Even you can, catscratch. In my opinion the comment by @chux is already enough. But a little more "decorative" explanation would not hurt.

Answer (score 5):

**C++ Standard - 7.6.1.6 Increment and decrement [expr.post.incr](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.incr)**

Your expression `*x++ = *y++;` applies the postfix operator `++` to each of the pointers `x` and `y` **after** the assignment from `*x = *y;` occurs. Essentially the value of each operand is its value before any increment is applied. The increment is applied after the value computation.

The standard language is:

> 1 The value of a postfix `++` expression is the value of its operand.
>
> [Note 1: The value obtained is a copy of the original value. — end
> note]
>
> The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. ... The value of the operand
> object is modified
> ([defns.access](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.access)) by adding 1 to
> it. The value computation of the ++ expression is sequenced before the
> modification of the operand object. ...
>
> 2 The operand of postfix `--` is decremented analogously to the
> postfix `++` operator.

[7.6.1.6 Increment and decrement - expr.post.incr](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.incr)

The equivalent section in the C-Standard is [6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.4)

Let me know if you have any further questions.